# Execution sequence of Group By, Having and Where clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am just confused with the execution sequence of a SQL query when we use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with a `WHERE` clause. Which one gets executed first?  What is the sequence?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

in order:

> **FROM** & **JOIN**s determine & filter rows
>   **WHERE** more filters on the rows
>   **GROUP BY** combines those rows into groups
>   **HAVING** filters groups
>   **ORDER BY** arranges the remaining rows/groups
>   **LIMIT** filters on the remaining rows/groups

Comment: is there any reference to this??

Comment: @Geshan, look into `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON`

Comment: Hi, I have one question. will the case statement when condition override the where condition ?

Comment: What about the select Clause. Is it in the Last?

Comment: @KM. Can you please clarify at which point in the list the select clause is executed? I think it’s immediately after “having”. (Someone correct me if I’m wrong.)

Answer (score 43):

Here is the complete sequence for sql server :

```
1.  FROM
2.  ON
3.  JOIN
4.  WHERE
5.  GROUP BY
6.  WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7.  HAVING
8.  SELECT
9.  DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

So from the above list, you can easily understand the execution sequence of **`GROUP BY, HAVING and WHERE`** which is :

```
1.  WHERE
2.  GROUP BY
3.  HAVING
```

[**Get more information about it from Microsoft**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

[More explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002068/5695953)

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON col = col2
WHERE table1.col = @val`
Here ON comes after join, and select comes first,  any explanations?

Comment: This is just the syntax of writing a SQL statement. The sequence i mentioned is the real order a SQL engine evaluates. That means if your query syntax is correct, then the engine evaluates `FROM` first, then `ON` and so on.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor You can read this http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/06/30/3187.aspx

Comment: If the WHERE comes before the SELECT, why does this return a row? select sum(1) from foo where 1 = 0

Comment: What about "INTO"?

Answer (score 12):

WHERE is first, then you GROUP the result of the query, and last but not least HAVING-clause is taken to filter the grouped result. This is the "logical" order, I don't know how this is technically implemented in the engine.

Comment: Worth adding that the optimizer may move clauses from HAVING to WHERE if they don't depend on an aggregate. This will not affect the results shown.

Answer (score 11):

**This is the SQL Order of execution of a Query,**

[image]

You can check order of execution with examples from this [article](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-order-of-operations/).

For you question below lines might be helpful and directly got from this [article](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution).

> 3. GROUP BY --> The remaining rows after the WHERE constraints are applied are then grouped based on common values in the column specified in the GROUP BY clause. As a result of the grouping, there will only be as many rows as there are unique values in that column. Implicitly, this means that you should only need to use this when you have aggregate functions in your query.

> 4. HAVING --> If the query has a GROUP BY clause, then the constraints in the HAVING clause are then applied to the grouped rows, discard the grouped rows that don't satisfy the constraint. Like the WHERE clause, aliases are also not accessible from this step in most databases.

References:-

- [**SQL Order of Operations**](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-order-of-operations/) (**recommended**)
- [SQL Lesson 12: Order of execution of a Query](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution)
- [SQL Query Order of Execution](https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/)
- [What Is the Order of Execution of an SQL Query?](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is implemented in the engine as Matthias said: WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING

Was trying to find a reference online that lists the entire sequence (i.e. "SELECT" comes right down at the bottom), but I can't find it. It was detailed in a "Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005" book I read not that long ago, by Solid Quality Learning

**Edit:** Found a link: http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/06/30/3187.aspx

Comment: Very nice explanation you linked to :-).

Comment: Link is dead. If you can fix that, it would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

In below Order

1. **FROM & JOIN**
2. **WHERE**
3. **GROUP BY**
4. **HAVING**
5. **SELECT**
6. **ORDER BY**
7. **LIMIT**

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12c, you can run code both in either sequence below:

```
Where
Group By
Having
```

Or

```
Where 
Having
Group by
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you need to do if you wish to implement:

- **WHERE**: Its need to execute the JOIN operations.
- **GROUP BY**: You specify Group by to "group" the results on the join, then it has to after the JOIN operation, after the WHERE usage.
- **HAVING**: HAVING is for filtering as GROUP BY expressions says. Then, it is executed after the GROUP BY.

The order is WHERE, GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: What you explained here is brilliant. It cleared my doubt regarding HAVING. So to summarise - GROUP BY & HAVING works same as SELECT & WHERE. HAVING clause always runs on COMPLETE table data taking the GROUP BY condition in picture and NOT ON GROUPED data.

Answer (score 0):

Having Clause may come prior/before the group by clause.

Example:
select * FROM test_std;
 ROLL_NO SNAME      DOB       TEACH

---

```
     1 John       27-AUG-18 Wills     
     2 Knit       27-AUG-18 Prestion  
     3 Perl       27-AUG-18 Wills     
     4 Ohrm       27-AUG-18 Woods     
     5 Smith      27-AUG-18 Charmy    
     6 Jony       27-AUG-18 Wills     
       Warner     20-NOV-18 Wills     
       Marsh      12-NOV-18 Langer    
       FINCH      18-OCT-18 Langer
```

9 rows selected.

select teach, count(*) count from test_std 
having count(*) > 1
group by TEACH ;

TEACH           COUNT

---

Langer              2
Wills               4

Answer (score 0):

- SELECT
- FROM
- JOIN (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL OUTER JOIN)
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That does not look like working syntax and it otherwise is surely not an explained answer to the sequence question, for that it looks too much like an attempt at actual syntax... Please have a look [answer].

Answer (score -2):

SELECT
FROM
JOINs
WHERE
GROUP By
HAVING
ORDER BY