# SQL - WHERE AGGREGATE>1

Tags: sql, aggregate, informix

Imagine I have a db table of Customers containing {id,username,firstname,lastname}

If I want to find how many instances there are of different firstnames I can do:

```
select firstname,count(*) from Customers group by 2 order by 1;

   username | count(*)
   ===================
   bob      |   1
   jeff     |   2
   adam     |   5
```

How do I write the same query to only return firstnames that occur more than once? i.e. in the above example only return the rows for jeff and adam.

Comment: Remember _HAVING_ filters at the group level, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130062/what-is-the-execution-sequence-of-group-by-having-and-where-clause-in-sql-server/1131076#1131076

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the `having` clause, like so:

```
select 
    firstname,
    count(*) 
from Customers 
group by firstname
having count(*) > 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`group by 2 order by 1` is terrible, I should say. Use proper column names if that's supported: this will drastically improve readability.

With that in mind,

```
select firstname, count(*) c 
from Customers 
group by firstname  
having count(*) > 1 -- Kudos to Shannon
order by c;
```

Comment: I don't know about Informix, but generally the column aliases from the select clause won't be available in the having clause, since having is evaluated earlier.

Comment: @Shannon: SQL never ceases to amaze me with its inconsistency. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for 'group by 2 order by 1 is terrible'.  However, it should also have been an error; at least, the server should have said "must group by firstname (non-aggregate in select-list) too".

Answer (score 2):

That's what the HAVING clause does.  I'm not sure if this will work in informix, but give it a shot:

```
select firstname, count(*) 
from Customers 
group by firstname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```