# Accesing Oracle ROWNUMBER with alias name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a Oracle Query

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT

    category_id,
    category_name,
    parent_category_id,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(category_name, '/'), '/') "ParentNames"       
FROM
    bg_categories
START WITH
    parent_category_id = - 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
    PRIOR category_id = parent_category_id
 )
 SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY 
      bco.ID desc
  ) AS SLNO,
bco.*,
cte.*,

(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        object_document obj
    WHERE
        obj.object_id = bco.id
        AND object_type_id = 85
) AS customobjects_doc_count 
 FROM
bg_custom_objects bco
JOIN cte ON ( cte.category_id = bco.category_id )  where SLNO between 10 and 25
```

This query works fine with out this 'where SLNO between 10 and 25' where statement at the end , but with this it's showing "SLNO invalid identifier " error.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap it with inline view/cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    category_id,
    category_name,
    parent_category_id,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(category_name, '/'), '/') "ParentNames"       
  FROM bg_categories
  START WITH parent_category_id = - 1
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
  PRIOR category_id = parent_category_id
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bco.ID desc) AS SLNO
      --,bco.* -- columns should be listed explicitly
      --,cte.* -- columns should be listed explicitly
  ,(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM object_document obj
    WHERE obj.object_id = bco.id
      AND object_type_id = 85
  ) AS customobjects_doc_count 
  FROM bg_custom_objects bco
  JOIN cte ON ( cte.category_id = bco.category_id )
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE SLNO BETWEEN 10 AND 25;
```

You cannot use aliases defined directly in `SELECT` in `WHERE` clause if both are on the same level because it is not visible [Can't refer to column counting the ocurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478494/5070879)

Additionally you could not move `ROW_NUMBER` to `WHERE` either [Why no windowed functions in where clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522288/5070879)

Comment: Thanks for response , i tried this one also with a extra cte previously but without where condition also it showing error "column ambiguously defined" and line 23

Comment: @Chanky Do not use  `alias.*`. Define  columns explicitly

Comment: Thanks , selected required columns, it's executing now