# SQL Execution Sequence of group by and having - Is Tutorial Quiz wrong or am I wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing some study for work on SQL queries.

I came across the following on TutorialsPoint and I'm confused as to why the answer is B and not C.

I have always been told that the GROUP BY Clause comes before HAVING and that HAVING always comes at the end. There is also a lot of documentation online to support my solution, for example: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_group_by_having.htm and [SQL query, sequence of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454800/sql-query-sequence-of-execution)

Can anyone tell me why B is correct in the following example and not C. The tutorial gives B as correct.

Consider the following schema-

```
STUDENTS(
    student_code, first_name, last_name, 
    email, phone_no, date_of_birth, 
    honours_subject, percentage_of_marks
);
```

Which of the following query will correctly list the average percentage of marks in each honours subject, when the average is more than 50 percent?

B.

```
select honours_subject,
    avg(percentage_of_marks)
from students
having avg(percentage_of_marks) > 50.0
group by honours_subject;
```

C.

```
select honours_subject,
    avg(percentage_of_marks)
from students
group by honours_subject
having avg(percentage_of_marks) > 50.0;
```

Comment: `B` is not syntactically correct.  Hence, it cannot be the correct answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Oddly Oracle (at least 11.x) allows B to work.  So the question is why is B more correct than C in this case...

Comment: Oracle [10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2065706), [11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065777) and [12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2065777) documentation show the `GROUP BY` must precede `HAVING`. The implementation, however, does not seem to respect this and can have any ordering. Strangely, 12c appears to omit being able to have a `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY` clause - something that is valid in the earlier version's syntax diagrams.

Comment: The tutorial is plain wrong. B is invalid standard SQL (although Oracle seems to allow it). Do you have a link to that tutorial?

Comment: We don't always need `group by`. This query works: `select avg(percentage_of_marks) from students having avg(percentage_of_marks) > 50` and it means: show me percentage only when percentage is greater than 50.

Comment: The questions keep etting jumbled around so I can't find it right now, but the link is here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql_online_quiz.htm

Comment: @Hairdo - You should look for a better resource.

Comment: Yes, I agree @GurV. I've changed to another tutorial. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Oracle does allows *B* to work, it gives a wrong idea of what actually happens. Additionally, as pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name, it is not valid as per *SQL standard* and may not work on other databases.

I think the *C* is more clear in terms of what is happening i.e. the `having` clause is evaluated after `group by`.

#### EDIT:

For those who think *B* doesn't work on Oracle, here is a demo:

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/UMT94863)

Comment: I must admit I didn't think you could have the having before the group by.

Comment: Thanks I was getting pretty confused with this one. Apologies for the styling issues.

Comment: @Hairdo - No problem. Glad to help out. The answer you accepted is wrong (at least as far as Oracle is concerned)

Comment: Additionally to the "more clear" part: B is not valid standard SQL, it will not work with e.g. Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Agreed. I've made the addition to the answer.

Comment: it does not even works on Oracle got an ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error

Comment: @Sandeep - It does. You may be doing some mistake in your query. Added a demo for you in the answer.

Comment: @GurV Yes it does having prior to group by with subquery refactoring works but if I use a table and then insert those values it won't allow me to do the same. I tried comparing the explain plan for both query interchanging the position of having and group by, the explain is identical for both queries. Do you have any idea why it works with dual but not with table data?

Comment: @GurV asked question here because it would have helped everyone

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial is off.

`HAVING` qualifies `GROUP BY`.  I suppose it's possible that there's some non-standard SQL parser out there that allows this syntax, but I don't really see why; I'm fairly certain Oracle would not support it (edit: apparently it does - weird).  It'd be like allowing someone to put a `WHERE` clause before `SELECT`

Comment: Yeah I know right? and I can't find a case where it matters on the results.  So I can't see why B is better than C or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

B query is wrong.

The syntax of query always needs to follow **WGHO**
W- where clause
G- Group by
H- Having
O- order by

Where and Order by are optional and you can only use having if you use a group by statement

Comment: B query is **not** wrong!! It's just not clear enough. Just try it up on Oracle

Comment: MySQL won't allow it

Comment: got an ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error when executed a query having prior to group by