# Max occurences of a given value in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table (pretty big one) with lots of columns, two of them being "post" and "user".
For a given "post", I want to know which "user" posted the most.

I was first thinking about getting all the entries WHERE (post='wanted_post') and then throw a PHP hack to find which "user" value I get the most, but given the large size of my table, and my poor knowledge of MySQL subtle calls, I am looking for a pure-MySQL way to get this value (the "user" id that posted the most on a given "post", basically).

Is it possible ? Or should I fall back on the hybrid SQL-PHP solution ?

Thanks,
Cystack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want... am I missing something?

```
SELECT user
FROM myTable
WHERE post='wanted_post'
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT:** Explanation of what this query does:

Hopefully the first three lines make sense to anyone familiar with SQL.  It's the last three lines that do the fun stuff.

1. `GROUP BY user` -- This collapses rows with identical values in the `user` column.  If this was the last line in the query, we might expect output something like this:

   ```
   +-------+
   | user  |
   +-------+
   | bob   |
   | alice |
   | joe   |
   ```
2. `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` -- `COUNT(*)` is an aggregate function, that works along with the previous `GROUP BY` clause.  It tallies all of the rows that are "collapsed" by the `GROUP BY` for each user.  It might be easier to understand what it's doing with a slightly modified statement, and it's potential output:

   ```
   SELECT user,COUNT(*)
   FROM myTable
   WHERE post='wanted_post'
   GROUP BY user;

   +-------+-------+
   | user  | count |
   +-------+-------+
   | bob   |     3 |
   | alice |     1 |
   | joe   |     8 |
   ```

   This is showing the number of posts per user.

   However, it's not strictly necessary to actually output the value of an aggregate function in this case--we can just use it for the ordering, and never actually output the data. (Of course if you want to know how many posts your top-poster posted, maybe you do want to include it in your output, as well.)

   The `DESC` keyword tells the database to sort in descending order, rather than the default of ascending order.

   Naturally, the sorted output would look something like this (assuming we leave the `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` list):

   ```
   +-------+-------+
   | user  | count |
   +-------+-------+
   | joe   |     8 |
   | bob   |     3 |
   | alice |     1 |
   ```
3. `LIMIT 1` -- This is probably the easiest to understand, as it just limits how many rows are returned.  Since we're sorting the list from most-posts to fewest-posts, and we only want the top poster, we just need the first result.  If you wanted the top 3 posters, you might instead use `LIMIT 3`.

Comment: Looks like it is. Apparently MySQL is way more powerful than I thought. Thanks again

Comment: Wow, I don't hear people calling MySQL "powerful" very often :)

Comment: But see, the syntax is unclear. Without the "ORDER BY" line, I'd get all the "user" that are linked to a "post", right ? How come when you add the ORDER BY, the COUNT(*) applies to each group separatey and not to the whoel request (thus returning the number of distinct "user") ?

Comment: @Cystack: The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are applied after the `GROUP BY` which is applied after the `WHERE`. See my answer, here, for the order of evaluation of clauses in queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685

Comment: holy schmoly, that makes MySQL as powerful as cascading stylesheets ! Awesome !

Comment: @Cystack: I've added what is probably way _too_ much explanation, but I was feeling bored and/or generous... let me know if you need more clarification :)

Comment: LOL! "holy schmoly, that makes MySQL as powerful as cascading stylesheets" -- Can I keep this quote? :)

Comment: @Cystack: Relational databases are much more powerful than stylesheets.

Comment: Keep all the quotes ! you gave me more than expected ! Thanks a lot for the lesson, thank you all, thank you stackoverflow !