# Error with having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select SUM (Bill) from ProductSaleReport group by PCI 
having MONTH(Date) between 1 and 3
```

Could any one please 
help me finding the issue.?

I am getting the errors:

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'ProductSaleReport.Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.
>   Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'ProductSaleReport.Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Well, what's the error? Though it doesn't look like you're using any aggregates - maybe you should be using WHERE instead?

Comment: I updated my question with the error. Please go through it.

Comment: Read to get a better understanding of differences between WHERE and GROUP BY http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MONTH(Date) is not a column you're grouped by, so it can't appear in having clause.
You can do like that:

```
select SUM (Bill) 
from ProductSaleReport
where MONTH(Date) between 1 and 3
group by PCI
```

Other way is

```
select SUM (Bill) 
from ProductSaleReport 
group by PCI, MONTH(Date) 
having MONTH(Date) between 1 and 3
```

but keep in mind that you will get result grouped by month as well as by PCI.

The difference between WHERE and HAVING explained here: [Using 'case expression column' in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)

Comment: The second version should be more efficient !

Comment: @marc_s This sample code works for me: SELECT fiscalmonth,count(*)
from inbalance
where fiscalyear=2011
group by fiscalmonth
having fiscalmonth between 1 and 3

Comment: @marc_s You see those "or the GROUP BY clause" words. If you group by MONTH(Date) you can use it in HAVING.

Comment: Pearl, both @Andrei wrote are working, beware that the use of having provides different results from that of the where clause because it is also grouping by month.

Comment: @niktrs It seems to me results will be the same. Maybe I've missed something. Please give some more details.

Comment: @Andrei the first query will return PCI * MONTH number of rows since it's grouped by month and pci while the second will return PCI number of rows since it's grouped by only pci.

Answer (score 8):

Use `WHERE` to filter before group by

`HAVING` is used to filter data after the group by occurs

```
select SUM (Bill) -- comment: you need to add the PCI column since you use it in the group by right?
from ProductSaleReport 
WHERE MONTH(Date) between 1 and 3
group by PCI
```

Answer (score 2):

`MONTH(Date)` is not a column you `SELECT`ed, so it can't appear in your `HAVING` clause.

If you meant to only `SUM` the `Bill`s from rows where the month is between 1 and 3, then that is a `WHERE` clause, not a `HAVING` clause.

If all the rows in each `PCI` group have the same `MONTH(Date)`, then you can add `MONTH(Date)` to your `SELECT` clause in order to use it in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: SELECT has nothing to do with HAVING. Only GROUP BY matters. And aggregate functions, of course. Error message says the same.

Comment: I need to group the data based on PCI value.
In the grop of PCI records, I need to find the sum of BILL Whose Bill date is on the month of jan,feb,march.

Comment: @Andrei Look at the example in the SQL Server manual... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx . The `HAVING` clause operates on the result set, it doesn't really matter how the result set was produced, columns that weren't in the `GROUP BY` clause can be in that result set and used in the `HAVING` clause for filtering.

Comment: @Pearl Then that's a `WHERE` condition, not `HAVING`. Change `HAVING` to `WHERE` and move it before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: There is aggregate function in where clause in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx.

Comment: @Andrei Don't know what you're talking about, there are no `WHERE` clauses in any queries on that page.

Comment: Right, which is what I said. The `HAVING` clause is filtering on a column that's in the result set because it was `SELECT`ed. That column is not in the `GROUP BY` clause at all.

Comment: MONTH(Date) is not an aggregate function. COUNT and SUM are.

Comment: But What is the difference between filtering out with having and where? Why should we place where conditon before group by?

Comment: Please explain the above. I am new to SQL and learning it. That would be great help if any one explain me.

Comment: @Pearl Buy a book. The comments box is not the place to explain how a RDBMS evaluates all the clauses of a query.

Comment: @Pearl: short story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

select SUM (Bill)
from ProductSaleReport
group by PCI
having MIN(MONTH(Date))>=1 and MAX(MONTH(Date))<=3