# SELECT COL1+COL2 as CalcColumn,* FROM TABLE WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE 100<COL1+COL2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

In a SELECT statement using a condition based on a calculated value, is it possible to include that calculated value without computing the calculated value twice - once in the selection and again in the condition?

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3):

You could put everything into a subquery and select from that

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
         SELECT COL1 + COL2 as CalcColumn
         FROM   Table
       ) q
WHERE  100 < CalcColumn
```

but as to performance, I expect this to be **slower** than your original query.

Comment: It won't be any slower. The plans will be the same. Of course the condition is completely unsargable and the OP would need an indexed computed column to avoid a scan.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any significant performance loss if you use the query as you wrote it. SQL handles it for you, I believe. My question would be, why are you using software from the previous century?

I just tried

```
SELECT Debit, Credit, Debit+Credit AS CalcColumn FROM JDT1 WHERE CalcColumn > 100
```

on SQL 2005 as suggested by a couple of guys and the error is:
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Invalid column name 'CalcColumn'.

Comment: Thanks. I keep asking the same question and as yet do not have an answer!

Comment: An explanation for why that error occurs is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COL1+COL2 as CalcColumn,* 
FROM TABLE WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 100 < CalcColumn
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a view to also have reusable calculation columns.

```
CREATE VIEW TableView
AS
SELECT COL1+COL2 as CalcColumn,*  FROM TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)  

GO

SELECT * FROM TableView WHERE 100 < CalcColumn
```