# Unknown column 'created_day' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: this is image of user feedback and]

```
SELECT *,DAYNAME(created_on) AS created_day FROM users_feedback WHERE created_day = 'wednesday'
```

When I execute above query it generate an error like below

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'created_day' in 'where clause'

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the where clause to

```
DAYNAME(created_on) = 'wednesday'
```

one can't use alias in where clause.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use aliases from SELECT in the WHERE clause.

```
… WHERE DAYNAME(created_on) = 'wednesday'
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: And a more detailed explanation (shameless self-ad): [Using expression column in where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)

Comment: Because that's how SQL works. SELECT is only evaluated after WHERE. See the answer that ypercube has linked above, it explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this?

```
SELECT *,DAYNAME(created_on) AS created_day
FROM users_feedback
WHERE DAYNAME(created_on) = 'wednesday'
```

Comment: Was this an answer, or a related question?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,DAYNAME(created_on) AS created_day 
FROM users_feedback 
WHERE DAYNAME(created_on) = 'wednesday
```

if you will use alias name in where clause, it will give performance issues and sometimes if you used it in wrong way it can give you error like yours way.

So best way is to use actual columns whenever needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,DAYNAME(created_on) AS created_day 
FROM users_feedback 
WHERE created_on= 'wednesday'
```

Нou have to mention the actual field name in where clause, where the value `'wednesday'` exists, hope so the above query will work

Comment: wednesday is already exist in my table using alias created_on