# SQL: Sorting a GROUP by Time and LIMIT the results

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table structure like:

```
Name    Time

Joe     2012-02-22 22:11:26.0
Joe     2012-02-22 21:01:23.0
Sue     2012-02-22 20:57:10.0
john    2012-02-22 18:13:36.0
Fred    2012-02-22 16:56:57.0
Joe     2012-02-22 14:38:45.0
Joe     2012-02-22 14:38:45.0
Ralph   2012-02-22 14:26:20.0
...     ...
(more Names and Times)
...     ...
john    2010-03-10 15:27:39.0
john    2010-03-10 15:46:59.0
```

I'm looking for the Top 3 Names Ordered by Time. So the result would be:

```
Joe, Sue, john
```

I began with a query like:

`SELECT Name FROM table ORDER BY LOWER(TIME) DESC`

So I wanted to Limit the result with:

`SELECT Name FROM table ORDER BY LOWER(TIME) DESC LIMIT 0 , 3`

But the result shows the first 3 rows as aspected:

```
Joe, Joe, Sue
```

Now I'm trying to group the query by Name first:

```
SELECT Name FROM table GROUP BY Name ORDER BY LOWER(TIME) DESC LIMIT 0 , 3
```

And yes that gives me 3 different names but in a unreproducible order.
Am I missing something here? What would be the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM table
ORDER BY Time DESC
LIMIT 3
```

So basically, you just need to add `DISTINCT` to your second query - this tells MySQL to select only unique values. There's no need in grouping. **UPD**: this is wrong, as `ORDER BY` will be applied after `DISTINCT`, as in most cases `DISTINCT` will use `GROUP BY`.

P.S. I don't see why you use `LOWER`. This function makes a string lower-case. But you're not operating strings, as the second column is of type `DATETIME` (I assume)?

**UPD:** You should use grouping, here's an example:

```
SELECT Name
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY MAX(Time) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Here the important thing is to take the maximum date/time from each group and order by that.

Comment: tried this. But also shows not the correct names. And yes I don't need the 'LOWER' function

Comment: This is really strange. What does it show and what would you expect?

Comment: I updated my answer. If it still doesn't work, it means that ordering doesn't work as expected. Check that the column has a type of `DATETIME`.

Comment: Couldn't figure out the logic yet. The result shows name from somewhere in the middle. I would expect `Joe, Sue, john`

Comment: YEPP. Your Updated Query was working as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: The first query is wrong because it essentially does: `SELECT Name FROM table GROUP BY Name ORDER BY time`. But there are multiple Times per Name, so becasue the Ordering is done **after** the grouping, a more or less random Time is chosen - and used for ordering.

Comment: @ypercube I thought the difference was that `ORDER BY` is applied before `DISTINCT`, but after `GROUP BY`. In other words, I thought that when you use `DISTINCT`, the result set is first ordered, and then rows are selected in the same order, but duplicate lines are not returned. Apparently, I was wrong about that.

Comment: No, AFAIK, `ORDER BY` is applied after `DISTINCT`

Comment: @ypercube you are right: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: Shameless self-ad: [SELECT: Order of execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)