# SELECT foo AS bar not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

My code:

```
SELECT pulpi_juegos.*, mapa.cat_id AS IDcategoria 
FROM pulpi_juegos 
INNER JOIN pulpi_categorias_mapa AS mapa ON pulpi_juegos.id=mapa.game_id 
WHERE pulpi_juegos.Estado != 1 
AND IDcategoria = 15 
ORDER BY pulpi_juegos.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,30;
```

Trouble is I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown column 'IDcategoria' in 'where clause'
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: [SELECT: order of processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL always executes the `SELECT` statement later then your `WHERE` statement.
Correct me if I'm wrong but SQL executes your statement as follows:

```
FROM
INNER JOIN
WHERE
AND
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

So as you can see now, when SQL comes to your `AND` statement, it does not know yet that `mapa.cat_id` is actually represented as `IDcategoria`. A simple solution would be changing the `IDcategoria` in your `AND` to `mapa.cat_id`.
So your query will be the following:

```
SELECT pulpi_juegos.*, mapa.cat_id AS IDcategoria 
FROM pulpi_juegos 
INNER JOIN pulpi_categorias_mapa AS mapa ON pulpi_juegos.id=mapa.game_id 
WHERE pulpi_juegos.Estado != 1 
AND mapa.cat_id = 15 
ORDER BY pulpi_juegos.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,30;
```

Comment: `FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

use mapa.cat_id instead of IDCategoria, because mysql executes the SELECT later.

```
SELECT pulpi_juegos.*, mapa.cat_id AS IDcategoria 
FROM pulpi_juegos 
INNER JOIN pulpi_categorias_mapa AS mapa ON pulpi_juegos.id=mapa.game_id 
WHERE pulpi_juegos.Estado != 1 
AND mapa.cat_id = 15 
ORDER BY pulpi_juegos.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,30;
```

like this order

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't put an alias in WHERE clause.

Use this:

```
SELECT pulpi_juegos.*, mapa.cat_id AS IDcategoria 
FROM pulpi_juegos 
INNER JOIN pulpi_categorias_mapa AS mapa ON pulpi_juegos.id=mapa.game_id 
WHERE pulpi_juegos.Estado != 1 
AND mapa.cat_id = 15 
ORDER BY pulpi_juegos.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,30;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use alias in where clause , instead you should write the column name . If want to use alias in where you have to use sub query like this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT pulpi_juegos.*, mapa.cat_id AS IDcategoria 
FROM pulpi_juegos 
INNER JOIN pulpi_categorias_mapa AS mapa ON pulpi_juegos.id=mapa.game_id 
WHERE pulpi_juegos.Estado != 1  
ORDER BY pulpi_juegos.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,30) WHERE IDcategoria = 15 ;
```

now it will work.