# MySQL GROUP BY and ORDER BY order

Tags: mysql, sql

Does it matter which comes after which? I mean if I do

```
SELECT * FROM  table GROUP BY x ORDER BY y
```

will the results first be grouped and then ordered?

Comment: It is a syntax error to put the `ORDER BY` first.  It is always evaluated last, and must occur after the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ORDER` is the last clause to be executed.

The order of execution

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause (*the reason why you can't use alias on this clause*)
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

<sup>[For more info, please click here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm)</sup>

Comment: @xyu added some source link :D

Comment: Also here, [an SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)

Answer (score 1):

- First `WHERE` condition
- Second `GROUP BY`
- Third one is `ORDER BY`

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY columnanme ORDER BY columnanmae
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, a `GROUP BY` clause has the side effect of sorting columns as well.  If you already have a `GROUP BY` clause in your query that produces the desired sort order, there's no need for an `ORDER BY`.