Effectively executing Conditional NOT IN Subquery with JOIN and GROUP BY
I need to adjust the following select statement to effectively filter out 523 records where 'first_date_purchased' is less than 'first_date_watched'. The following select statement returns 20778 records, of which 20255 should remain.
    SELECT se.student_id,
           si.date_registered,
           MIN(se.date_watched) AS first_date_watched,
           MIN(sp.date_purchased) AS first_date_purchased
    FROM student_engagement se
      LEFT JOIN student_info si ON se.student_id = si.student_id
      LEFT JOIN student_purchases sp ON se.student_id = sp.student_id
    GROUP BY se.student_id
    ORDER BY- first_date_purchased DESC
    -- Gives 20778 records

I have come up with the following solution, using NOT IN, but it has a substantial runtime of 1 minute. Initially I cancelled the process, but was advised by @Akina to include a sample dataset, on which both this query and another solution by @Raphi worked perfectly. My query is as follows:
    SELECT se.student_id,
           si.date_registered,
           MIN(se.date_watched) AS first_date_watched,
           MIN(sp.date_purchased) AS first_date_purchased
    FROM student_engagement se
      LEFT JOIN student_info si ON se.student_id = si.student_id
      LEFT JOIN student_purchases sp ON se.student_id = sp.student_id
    WHERE se.student_id NOT IN (SELECT sp2.student_id
                                FROM student_purchases sp2
                                WHERE sp2.date_purchased < se.date_watched)
    GROUP BY se.student_id
    ORDER BY- first_date_purchased DESC;
    -- Gives 20255 records

Although, I wanted to complete all filtering within a single select statement, I initially cast the unfiltered result of 20778 records into a new table called 'unfiltered_true_dataset' and got the desired filtering done with the following select statement based on that:
    SELECT *
    FROM unfiltered_true_dataset
    WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id
                             FROM unfiltered_true_dataset
                             WHERE first_date_purchased < first_date_watched)
    -- Successfully obtained 20255 records

My question is whether there might be a more effective way to apply such a filter in a single select statement? Here is a sample dataset. The unfiltered select stetement returns 5 records, where the solution using the NOT IN subquery correctly returns only 4 records:
    CREATE TABLE `student_info` 
    (`student_id` INT NOT NULL, 
    `date_registered` DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`));
    
    INSERT INTO `student_info` VALUES
    (255193, '2021-12-01'),(255194, '2021-12-01'),(255196, '2021-12-01'),
    (255198, '2021-12-01'),(255199, '2021-12-01'),(255200, '2021-12-01'),
    (255201, '2021-12-01'),(255203, '2021-12-01'),(255204, '2021-12-01'),
    (255205, '2021-12-01');
    -- Full dataset has 40979 records
    
    CREATE TABLE `student_engagement` 
    (`student_id` INT DEFAULT NULL, 
    `date_watched` DATE DEFAULT NULL);
    
    INSERT INTO `student_engagement` VALUES
    (255200, '2021-12-01'),(255201, '2021-12-02'),(255201, '2021-12-06'),
    (255201, '2021-12-08'),(255201, '2022-10-05'),(255203, '2022-03-08'),
    (255203, '2022-03-17'),(255203, '2022-03-23'),(255203, '2021-12-01'),
    (255203, '2022-01-25'),(255203, '2022-01-26'),(255203, '2022-01-27'),
    (255203, '2022-02-08'),(255203, '2022-02-09'),(255203, '2022-02-21'),
    (255203, '2022-02-22'),(255203, '2022-02-23'),(255204, '2021-12-01'),
    (255204, '2021-12-02'),(255204, '2021-12-03'),(255204, '2021-12-14'),
    (255204, '2021-12-17'),(255204, '2021-12-07'),(255204, '2021-12-05'),
    (255204, '2021-12-09'),(255204, '2021-12-23'),(255204, '2022-01-11'),
    (255204, '2022-01-18'),(255204, '2022-03-05'),(255204, '2022-06-19'),
    (255204, '2022-07-06'),(255204, '2021-12-04'),(255204, '2021-12-18'),
    (255204, '2021-12-20'),(255204, '2021-12-29'),(255204, '2022-03-28'),
    (255204, '2022-03-31'),(255204, '2022-07-17'),(255204, '2022-07-21'),
    (255204, '2022-07-31'),(255204, '2021-12-12'),(255204, '2021-12-13'),
    (255204, '2021-12-21'),(255204, '2021-12-27'),(255204, '2022-01-07'),
    (255204, '2021-12-08'),(255204, '2022-01-27'),(255205, '2021-12-01'),
    (255205, '2021-12-02'),(255205, '2021-12-07'),(255205, '2022-01-22'),
    (255205, '2022-04-05');
    -- Full dataset has 74246 records
    
    CREATE TABLE `student_purchases` 
    (`purchase_id` INT NOT NULL, 
    `student_id` INT DEFAULT NULL, 
    `date_purchased` DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`purchase_id`));
    
    INSERT INTO `student_purchases` VALUES
    (15055, 255201, '2021-12-01'),(15057, 255203, '2021-12-01'),
    (15059, 255204, '2021-12-01'),(15060, 255196, '2021-12-01');
    -- Full dataset has 5922 records

The objective is to filter out the records where 'first_date_purchased' is less than 'first_date_watched' in a single select statement, in the most effective way possible. I'm writing this query as a student in Data Analysis and am still new to programming in general.
Thank you in advance for you assistance!

See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, provide a sample (7-10 rows) and desired output for it according to #5 and #3.

In your second query you're operating on the MIN() values of se.date_watched and sp.date_purchased while in your initial query in the NOT IN you're referencing to the actual values of the tables: WHERE sp2.date_purchased < se.date_watched

@Raphi1 if I add in MIN() into the second query also, I get "Invalid use of group function". This is probably because its an aggregate being used in a WHERE clause? If I try to run it as a HAVING clause, after GROUP BY, I get the same error. Leaving MIN() out again, se.date_watched is an unknown column. It is quite intricate for me. I could perhaps do the joins differently, to avoid having to reference two tables in a WHERE / HAVING clause? (P.S. how do you format text here so it appears "shaded bold" like you have?)

Thank you very much @Akina. I will have a good read-through and implement in subsequent questions. I see there is also some guidelines in the Tags section for MySQL.

@Akina this is an example of a row that should not be in the final output: student_id: 283300; date_registered: 2022-07-31; first_date_watched: 2022-08-07; first_date_purchased: 2022-08-03; date_diff_reg_watch: 7; date_diff_watch_purch: -4. The last two columns were added with DATEDIFF to display the the difference in days between the registration date and the date of first-time engagement and that of the date of first-time engagement and the date of first-time purchase. The -4 here indicates that the watch date was four days later than the purchase date.

Please add sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO into the question text, with proper formatting and desired output for this sample data.

@KarelPrinsloo For formatting a whole code block you're using the triple '```' while for only single words you're using the single '`'. Btw. code block is not working in comments

If this is your actual DDL, you should create some indexes for the columns you're joining on: student_purchases.student_id and student_engagement.student_id. If it's still too slow, consider creating an index on the columns where you're calculating the MIN of

Thank you @Raphi for pointing out where indexing applies and I will have a go at it! Now I am getting a better understanding of the big picture. I apologize for asking the initial question when I haven't made absolutely sure all was clear on my side. I think that I might need to delete the question as a whole, as my query shows part of a solution to a course project I am doing. If you would like to post your comment about indexing as an answer, I will otherwise accept it. Thank you once more!

Don't you just need a having clause then?      HAVING first_date_purchased >=first_date_watched'  having is effectively a where clause which executes after the select statement and group by have done their work.  for example: https://dbfiddle.uk/St84Yu2y returns 2 records.  then null first_date_purchased are excluded.  or https://dbfiddle.uk/xLSFVBR9 if you want to include Null first_date_purchased. which can't be evaluated based on equality.

Consider:
Using a HAVING clause which executes like a where clause AFTER the selected values and aggregation is complete.
Note: Standard SQL is to include all non-aggregated selected objects in the GROUP BY clause. So, I added the date_registered to the group by. MySQL supports this syntax but it can be dangerous to use if you don't fully understand what it's doing.   (Basically it's free to pick any value in the group even if those values are different) so if a student_Id could have different date_Registered for some reason, you could get different results in each run.  STANDARD SQL is to always group by all values not aggregated in the select. Other RDBMS would not even allow your current query to run.
Furthermore null evaluation in a in/not in is also suspect.  Exists/not exists and correlation may be faster; but I don't see a reason to use it since I believe the Having clause will meet your need.
Demo dbfiddle.uk
   SELECT se.student_id,
           si.date_registered,
           MIN(se.date_watched) AS first_date_watched,
           MIN(sp.date_purchased) AS first_date_purchased
    FROM student_engagement se
      LEFT JOIN student_info si ON se.student_id = si.student_id
      LEFT JOIN student_purchases sp ON se.student_id = sp.student_id
    GROUP BY se.student_id, si.date_registered
    HAVING first_date_purchased >= first_date_watched
     or first_date_purchased is null
    -- or use this in the having coalesce(first_date_purchased,first_date_watched) >= first_date_watched
    ORDER BY first_date_purchased DESC

However, it's odd that you expect 4 records.  Since first_date_purchased is null on two of the 5 records it would fail equality checks.  Logically How is a Null value on first_date_purchased for students 255200, 255205 <= first_date_watched? but you seem to want them so we can either coalesce or use an or in the having.
Either of these do not subjet you to a subquery or additional query as desired; but I'm unsure if either is more performant w/o a full dataset / knowledge of your indexes etc.

This is such a great explanation to someone new in the field. I have failed at structuring the having clause and resulted to using a NOT IN subquery. The subquery runs under 1 second with indexing, as @Raphi suggested, but both cases of the HAVING clause you suggested already run in 0.5 of a second without indexing applied. This is the answer I was after from the start and must have been close myself, but could not get it to form a sound argument.

Just to clarify where you asked: "Logically How is a Null value on first_date_purchased for students 255200, 255205 <= first_date_watched?" The Null values in First_date_purchased mean that no purchase has been made. The goal of the extraction is to analyze the conversion rate (subscribing to a paid plan) of students who have already watched a lecture. Cases where they've subscribed before watching their first lecture, are outside of the scope of the study. The goal being to analyze the effectiveness of offering free course material.

SQL's order of operations is not top down like traditional programming languages.  https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-order-of-operations/  and what I said isn't technically accurate, the having and select order of execution is ambiguous.  Many say the select occurs after the having, but then how would it know about the aliased (min) columns from the select... so it's a bit confusing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123485/in-sql-is-having-processed-before-or-after-select or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048672/why-cant-i-use-an-alias-for-an-aggregate-in-a-having-clause

I think it boils down to engine optimizer and each RDBMS is different in it's implementation.  Some I think are able to find the alias and substitute in the appropriate  formula for the alias when building the SQL statement to execute.  But this will vary by engine.  So while this works in my example; it may not work in Say MSFT SQL Server. and as new versions are released, this may change.

So it could be written as: the 3rd example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/vElh5W3P to achieve the same effect. for RDBMS which don't support the look ahead aliasing of the group by that mySQL supports in this case.

More detail: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases

It is truly a wonderful insight, knowing that MySQL accepts aliasing in the having clause, where standard SQL does not allow this due to order of operations etc. Thank you for providing the select statement that would otherwise work if not run in MySQL and for linking to additional reading material about the subject!

If this is your actual DDL, you should create some indexes for the columns you're joining on:
student_purchases.student_id and student_engagement.student_id.
If it's still too slow, consider creating an index on the columns where you're calculating the MIN of
I'm not 100% sure about the syntax for mysql but you should get the idea ;)
CREATE INDEX sp_student_id ON student_purchases (`student_id`);
CREATE INDEX se_student_id ON student_engagement (`student_id`);

As a rule of thumb, you would typically create an index on your foreign key columns, as these are typically the columns, you're joining on.

Awesome, the query now executes in just under a second! Thank you very much for the explanation! I really wanted to mark your answer as the solution, as it technically is the best way when using a NOT IN subquery, but @xQbert answered the question behind my question, suggesting a correct alternative approach to the problem. Many thanks once more!
