# Parameter Case statement in Where clause

Tags: parameters, sql-server-2012

Need to separate orders if they are 'Millwork' or 'Not Millwork'. A parameter allows the user to select the order type when generating their report.

Moved the parameter Case statement from the Select to the Where clause per [Stack entry #6545664](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/)

The whole report returns data successfully in SQL Server but not in Report Server.

@OrderClass is the parameter problem. It returns two values: MillworkOnly and NonMillwork

```
--Parameter @OrderClass
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE 
WHEN XGENERALDESCRIPTION LIKE 'MILLWORK%' THEN 'MillworkOnly'
ELSE 'NonMillwork'
END
FROM SPV3SALESDOCUMENT
```

This statement below returns the main report data. It runs successfully in SQL Server 2012 as is but only runs successfully in Report Server when the Case statement at the end of the Where clause is commented out (as shown).

Suspecting the issue could be the parameter results are not yet available to the main statement when it runs.

How does a parameter run within a Where clause?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
H.DOCID
, H.CUSTNAME
, H.CUSTNMBR
, H.PRSTADCD
, L.ITEMCODE
, H.ShipToName
, H.ADDRESS1
, H.ADDRESS2
, H.ADDRESS3
, H.CITY
, H.STATE
, H.ZIPCODE
, H.SLPRSNID
, H.SALSTERR
, H.MODIFDT
, H.SOPSTATUS
, H.SOPTYPE
, H.SOPNUMBE
, H.CSTPONBR
, H.SHIPMTHD
, L.LNITMSEQ
, L.ITEMNMBR
, L.ITEMDESC
, L.NONINVEN
, L.UOFM
, L.LOCNCODE
, L.UNITPRCE
, L.XTNDPRCE
, L.QUANTITY
, L.ATYALLOC
, L.QTYFULFI
, L.ReqShipDate
, DATEADD(DAY, 2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, L.ReqShipDate), L.ReqShipDate) as nWkOf
, L.FUFILDAT
, SM.MANUFACTUREORDER_I
, a.xSpiPM
, a.xCustPM
, a.xCeilingType
, a.xCeilingheight
, a.xLatitude
, a.xLongitude
, s.xSignatureRequired
, s.xDrvMilesToStore
, s.xFrtMilesToStore
, s.xGeneralDescription


FROM SOP10200 AS L --ORDER LINES

INNER JOIN SOP10100 AS H --ORDER HEADER
    ON L.SOPTYPE = H.SOPTYPE 
    AND L.SOPNUMBE = H.SOPNUMBE 

INNER JOIN IS010001 AS SM --SOPMOP LINK
    ON L.SOPNUMBE = SM.SOPNUMBE 
    AND L.SOPTYPE = SM.SOPTYPE 
    AND L.LNITMSEQ = SM.LNITMSEQ 
    AND L.CMPNTSEQ = SM.CMPNTSEQ

LEFT JOIN spvCustomerAddr AS A --SP UDF
    ON H.CUSTNMBR = A.Customer_Num 
    AND H.PRSTADCD = A.Address_Code

LEFT JOIN spv3SalesDocument AS S --SP UDF
    ON L.SOPNUMBE = s.Sales_Doc_Num

WHERE
H.VOIDSTTS = 0 
AND L.ITEMNMBR NOT LIKE '1%' 
AND (L.ReqShipDate BETWEEN (@StartDate) and (@EndDate)) 
AND @OrderClass = 
    CASE 
    WHEN s.xGeneralDescription LIKE 'MILLWORK%' THEN 'MillworkOnly'
    ELSE 'NonMillwork'
    END
AND H.SLPRSNID in (@AccountRepName) 
AND H.CUSTNAME in (@CustOrderName) 
AND H.docid = @OrderType AND L.QUANTITY <> 0 
AND (L.QUANTITY - L.QTYFULFI) >= (@FulfilledLines);
```

Report Server error =

`For more information about this error navigate to the report server on
the local server machine, or enable remote errors
---------------------------- Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
---------------------------- An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)`

Comment: At the end of your CASE, is that `END = @OrderClass` just a copy/paste typo or is that a new syntax on 2012 I'm not aware of?

Comment: I was about the ask the same about the `END = @OrderClass` syntax and that being the parameter you say is causing trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT - NEW SUGGESTION

Okay - if this doesn't work in Report

```
AND @OrderClass = 
    CASE 
    WHEN s.xGeneralDescription LIKE 'MILLWORK%' THEN 'MillworkOnly'
    ELSE 'NonMillwork'
    END
```

It's possible Reporting doesn't like the parameter at the start - and it clearly doesn't mind it at the backend.

It seems to be happening because of the naked parameter starting the comparison clause.

I wonder if you could wrap it differently

How about

```
AND 
    (SELECT 
        CASE 
        WHEN s.xGeneralDescription LIKE 'MILLWORK%' THEN 'MillworkOnly'
        ELSE 'NonMillwork'
        END
    ) IN (@OrderClass)
```

Comment: Moved the parameter name to the beginning of the case statement. However, still getting the same Report Server error.

This short screencast video may better illustrate the culprit: [http://youtu.be/6OBmA9J0-xY?hd=1](http://youtu.be/6OBmA9J0-xY?hd=1)
      
Originally had the case statement in Select so errantly swapped the fieldname position with the parameter. Thanks for correcting @JUICED_IT and dbmitch.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for sticking with me @dbmitch

Comment: Okay - had a look at what IS working and came up with new suggestion to try

Comment: This second case statement works successfully both in SQL Server and the seemingly temperamental Report Server. Thanks so much @dbmitch for your time and talent. Also, my millwork staff thanks you.

Comment: Phewh, glad it finally worked - you found a new 'feature' of Report Server!