# When arithmetic expressions are executed in Oracle SQL queries?

Tags: query-optimization, oracle12c, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

When I execute a query including arithmetic operations in the SELECT statement like:

```
SELECT a*5 FROM table;
```

When `a*5` will be executed in terms of the order of the query execution? I mean, is it before the ORDER BY, HAVING, and GROUP BY clauses? Or after or before all these?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your query does not have an `ORDER BY`, `HAVING` or a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)

Comment: @Stu That question is for SQL Server and not Oracle; if you can find an equivalent question for Oracle then it maybe a duplicate (although this question is subtly different as it is talking about where in that order the arithmetic is evaluated).

Comment: True it's tagged for Sqlserver but I think the principles apply to most platforms inc Oracle, there's also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842262/oracle-sql-clause-evaluation-order)

Comment: @Stu has it right. If the order of execution were different, the query language wouldn't be SQL, it would be something else.

Comment: @mT0 No it is not for SQL Server, it is for Oracle.