# MySQL - Group BY GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate, group-concat

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
     issue.`sequence` AS issue_sequence,
     issue.`description` AS issue_description,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(issue_category.`name`) SEPARATOR ', ') AS issue_category_name,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(approach.`name`) SEPARATOR ', ') AS approach_name,
     issue_approach.`issue_id` AS issue_approach_issue_id,
     issue_approach.`approach_id` AS issue_approach_approach_id
FROM
     `approach` approach 
     INNER JOIN `issue_approach` issue_approach ON approach.`id` = issue_approach.`approach_id`
     INNER JOIN `issue` issue ON issue_approach.`issue_id` = issue.`id`
     INNER JOIN `project` project ON issue.`project` = project.`id`
     INNER JOIN `tenant` tenant ON project.`tenant_id` = tenant.`id`
     INNER JOIN `issue_category` issue_category ON project.`id` = issue_category.`project`
     INNER JOIN `user` user ON tenant.`id` = user.`tenant_id`
WHERE user.id = 1 AND project.id = 1
GROUP BY issue_category_name
ORDER BY issue_category.`name`, issue.`sequence`
```

I am having a problem with this line:

```
GROUP BY issue_category_name
```

Apparently, MySQL can't seem to Group by the alias for by GROUP_CONCAT result.
I am not really an expert with SQL, but is there a way I can group using the result of GROUP_CONCAT?

Sample data;

Categories: Network, Servers
Issue Id: 1
Description: Some description
Approaches: Some approaches to resolve the issue.

Basically, an issue can belong to one or many categories. I am concatenating categories for each issue. What i want to do is group the results by the result of concatenation of categories. So for example group issues whose categories are Network,Servers.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the error message said ?

Comment: What is the query supposed to do? Can you either describe in words or provide sample data and wanted output?

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense.  What is your goal?

Answer (score 4):

Im not a MySQL  user, but change your group by to

```
 Group By GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(issue_category.`name`) SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Answer (score 2):

With reference to [SQL EXECUTION ORDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130062/what-is-the-execution-sequence-of-group-by-having-and-where-clause-in-sql-server), the reason why this will not work is because the select statement is the last statement to be executed so that sql engine will not be knowing your column alias while grouping the records as GROUP BY occurs before SELECT. So that as Charles Bretana's answer suggests, put

```
Group By GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(issue_category.`name`) SEPARATOR ', ')
```

in your group by clause. It will work fine then.

Hope this helps you.