# PHP mysql Order by and Group By query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

In my order history, I am currently listing all the customers previous orders, however, not in date order.
My current query is :

```
SELECT OrderItemID, Date
FROM orderitems
WHERE OrderID=$orderid
GROUP BY OrderID;
```

After this query, I use a while loop, for each order found, to print the past order in a table. 
However I want to print past orders by 'ORDER BY Date'. After the GROUPBY I put ORDER BY Date Desc, but had no difference in results printing.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're grouping by OrderID, which OrderItemID and Date are you actually wanting to retrieve if there are several items?

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense on several levels.  You are grouping by `OrderId` but selecting `OrderItemId`.  The columns in the `select` do not use any aggregation functions.  You are selecting only one `OrderId` and then aggregating by it.  Can you edit the question with sample data and your desired results?

Comment: check this link...

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130062/what-is-the-execution-sequence-of-group-by-having-and-where-clause-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Since you are filtering the records with `OrderID`, why do you need to `GROUP BY` it?

```
SELECT OrderItemID, Date
FROM orderitems
WHERE OrderID=$orderid
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `OrderItems` would have the date of the order.  Based on the text, I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT OrderID, Date
FROM Orders o
WHERE CustomerId = $CustomerId
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```