# Reuse calculated column in HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please look at the following query

```
SELECT 
    product_id, SUM(unit_price * quantity) Total
FROM 
    tblOrders
GROUP BY 
    product_id
HAVING
    SUM(unit_price * quantity) > 1000
```

The above query works fine. But you can see in there query, `Total` is a calculated column, and the same calculation is used again in the `HAVING` clause.

How can I avoid using this same calculation in the `HAVING` clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after doing some more study in this subject last couple of days, i have found my answer. In fact, my query what i posted in the question is completely correct, just we can write that query in other way(s), but we can't avoid to reuse the calculation actually, even though we make the query `nested` like below :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id,
           SUM(unit_price * quantity) Total
    FROM tblOrders
    GROUP BY product_id
) A
WHERE A.Total > 1000;
```

This is just because the order of logical processing of the `SELECT` statement. Look at the below order :

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

Notice the order of `SELECT` statement, any column aliases or derived columns defined in `SELECT` statement cannot be referenced by preceding clauses whose orders are less than 8. You can get more information about it [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way is to avoid further calculation using `Subquery` instead use of `HAVING` Clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id,
           SUM(unit_price * quantity) Total
    FROM tblOrders
    GROUP BY product_id
) A
WHERE A.Total > 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregation function.  I would guess that you really want:

```
select product_id, sum(unit_price * quantity) as Total
from tblOrders
group by product_id
having sum(unit_price * quantity) > 1000;
```

Your original query is syntactically incorrect and should return a compiler error on SQL Server -- because `unit_price * quantity` is not a `group by` key.

Comment: `sum` was there already, i did wrong while posting here. Can i not use `Total` in the `HAVING` clause instead of writing `sum(unit_price * quantity)` again?