# Add filter on column which subtract to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have long store procedure in whcih i want Add filter on this Column

```
select (PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted) as Unapplied, BalancDue from ERAMaster
 where Unapplied = 22
```

but i run the query they give me error invalid column name. any one tell me the write way to Add filter on Unapplied Column

Comment: it should be `where PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted = 22`. There is no way to use column alias in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below :

```
select * from 
(
    select (PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted) as Unapplied, BalancDue from ERAMaster
) as T where Unapplied = 22
```

Or like this :

```
select (PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted) as Unapplied, BalancDue from ERAMaster
where PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted = 22
```

Comment: Please read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002068/5695953) to get more useful information.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
select (PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted) as Unapplied, BalancDue from ERAMaster
 where (PaymentAmount-PaymentPosted) = 22
```

'Unapplied' is not a column name it is only alias.