# SQL Operator Precedence with braces

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a SQL query I do not quite understand regarding operator precedence:

```
SELECT
foo,
count(*)
FROM
A
JOIN (SELECT
  SUM(IF(bar = 2,1,0)) as bar_sum,
  SUM(IF(foo >= 1,1,0)) as foo,
  SUM(1) as sum_1
  FROM
  B
  ) as sums
GROUP BY
id,
bar_sum,
foo,
sum_1
ON A.id = B.id
```

does the `GROUP BY` from outer brace really apply to the inner one?
Note, I need to port this SQL from Hive to Spark scala Dataframe API so I really need to get operator precedence right. From [What is the execution sequence of Group By, Having and Where clause in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130062/what-is-the-execution-sequence-of-group-by-having-and-where-clause-in-sql-serve) it looks like in general this is true, but I did not find any documentation regarding the `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query looks incorrect (there is missing `ON` clause)

```
SELECT foo,count(*)
FROM A
JOIN (SELECT SUM(IF(bar = 2,1,0)) as bar_sum,
             SUM(IF(foo >= 1,1,0)) as foo,
             SUM(1) as sum_1
      FROM   B) as sums  -- should be `ON`
GROUP BY id, bar_sum, foo, sum_1;
        -- looks like grouping by sum_1, bar_sum is superflous
```

The `GROUP BY` is applied only to outer query. Please note that inner query will return single row.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(bar = 2,1,0)) as bar_sum,
       SUM(IF(foo >= 1,1,0)) as foo,
       SUM(1) as sum_1
FROM   B
-- single row
```

Then you join single row to table A and get as many rows as distinct (id,foo) values.