# Combining sum() of similar entry's, and including a WHERE clause SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I am trying to add up the the numbers from **amount**, if the **booking_id** matches. I have been having trouble with summing these numbers as well as adding in a WHERE clause.

This is my code so far

***At this time it is summing the numbers correctly, although if I add in the where it doesn't show any results***

`select *, Sum(amount) FROM payment group by booking_id where booking_id = 1`

I have tried some methods like adding queries in queries but I have had no luck. The results I'm attempting to get are below.

```
booking_id   amount
----------------------
      1    |  5
      2    |  6
      1    |  6
      3    |  2
      3    |  3
      4    |  4
```

Output should be:

```
booking_id   amount
    ----------------------
          1    |  11
          2    |  6
          3    |  5
          4    |  4
```

I am attempting to group the results so that booking_id with a value of 1 will return a sum of 5+6.

My goal is to be able to add together the amounts that have the same booking id. As well as to be able to include a WHERE clause within this query

Comment: Wrong order, WHERE goes before GROUP BY.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't change anything @jarlh

Comment: Skip the WHERE. Do GROUP BY to get all booking_id's as requested.

Comment: What @jarlh says is correct http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e59e0c/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all booking_id's as requested, simply skip the `WHERE` clause:

```
select booking_id, Sum(amount)
FROM payment
group by booking_id
```

To get all booking_id's for a specific ident (as later requested), add the `WHERE` clause:

```
select booking_id, Sum(amount)
FROM payment
where client_id = 123
group by booking_id
```

Comment: That would be good, although I need to only get these results from a specific person. For example if client_id was in the database, and I want to only include that specific client.

Comment: I checked the link and it does seam to be working. Its just not wanting to work with what I have through. must be something I'm missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It really should be working, but for some reason their is something stoping it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Where should be before group by

```
select booking_id , Sum(amount) FROM payment 
where booking_id = 1
group by booking_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong only in order to write sql

```
   select booking_id, Sum(amount) FROM payment
   where client_id = 1 -- your condition 
   group by booking_id
```

[Check this link for order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130062/what-is-the-execution-sequence-of-group-by-having-and-where-clause-in-sql-serve)